# Как осуществить вставку элементов в пустой массив по индексу?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть 2 массива. Один массив, он состоит из 5 пустых элементов.
Второй массив может состоять из элементов вида (приходит с бэка и может содержать элементы с разными index):

```
const array = [
  {id: '12727ssksks2', index: 0, item: '120dd2020'},
  {id: '12727dhdhdhd2', index: 2, item: '120dd2020'},
  {id: '1272ssmmss72', index: 1, item: '120dd2020'}
]
```

Нужно произвести вставку по индексу (index) элементов из пришедшего массива в пустой и получить массив из 5 элементов с новыми элементами и пустыми соответственно. 
То есть каждый раз заполнять пустой массив новыми данными по индексу. Плюс если данные не обновились элемента по тому индексу или вообще всех элементов, ничего не делать (некое кэширование) , так как каждые 5 секунд данные приходят с бэка и этот массив будет обновляться в том случае, если пришли новые элементы.

Comment: так а в чем проблема? чтобы присвоить по индексу просто: `arr[index] = value`

Answer (score 1):

```
let a=new Array(5).fill(null)
array.forEach(i=>a[i.index]=i)
```